# Is it possible to load an eclipse Java project using JDT in the headless mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, headless

I have an eclipse Java project and want to get information like project source dir, classpaths, etc. My current implementation parses the `.project` file. But as I didn't find any official documentation describing the structure of the `.project` file, I have some concerns for the robustness of this approach.

A more convenient and robust way would be to use JDT (headlessly) to load the project and get the relevant information from the `IJavaProject` object.

Although the developer guide of JDT says

> JDT Core packages give you access to the Java model objects and headless Java IDE infrastructure.

all the examples I can find opening an existing Java project get the `IJavaProject` object from projects within a `workspace` or use an `IProject` object. But I couldn't find the way to add a project to the `workspace` or to construct a `IProject/IJavaProject` from a path to `.project` file.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, and can all be done through clear and stable API.** `org.eclipse.jdt.core` is a plug-in, just like `org.eclipse.core.resources` (which is where you would get an `IWorkspace` instance), and they both expect to be running *within* an **Eclipse runtime**, which can be headless if that's how you write your **Eclipse Application**. JDT uses the `.classpath` file to record where sources, libraries, and build output are, and what abstracted references to libraries to use, while the `.project` file is what records what kind of project it is in general--Java, PHP, Web, some combination of those or others--and a little more information about what builders to execute.

So make yourself a headless Eclipse Application, or package your end-goal functionality inside of one.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_an_Eclipse_application%3F
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_are_extensions_and_extension_points%3F
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_runtime_applications.html?cp=2_1_1_27

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin.html#getWorkspace--
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore.html#getJavaCore--
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject.html#getResolvedClasspath-boolean-

Comment: Getting the `Workspace` and the `JavaCore` is useful, but my problem is actually with getting/constructing the `IJavaProject` object, which is needed to call `getResolvedClasspath`.

Comment: Take a good look through those two classes. One will give you an IProject, the other can use that to give you the corresponding IJavaProject.

Comment: Do you mean the `JavaCore.create(IProject)` method? It requires an `IProject` argument, while the only implementer of `IProject`, i.e. `Project`, has a `protected` constructor. `WorkspaceRoot.getProject(String)` returns a `Project`, but I need a `Workspace` to get a `WorkspaceRoot`. In a headless setting, calling `ResourcePlugin.getWorkspace()` directly triggers an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed` because `ResourcePlugin.workspace` is not initialized. To initialize it, one has to call `ResourcePlugin.start` with a `BundleContext`. ... Did I miss anything?

Comment: Or could you please provide a short example of how this is done? That would be great.

Comment: You don't create the concrete instances, you get them from the workspace that the ResourcesPlugin gave you. The implementations are internal, so ignore them for now; you're not going to create the instances yourself. All of the relevant methods return objects with the public interfaces, and that's enough to chain together and get you where you want to go. So for the `IProject` that `JavaCore` needs, get it from the `IWorkspace` that the ResourcesPlugin gave you.

And yes, you missed the part where i said this has to be running within an Eclipse Application to work.

Comment: It appears that a dependency on `jdt.core` is not enough for JDT to work in headless mode, you'll also have (runtime) dependencies on `jdt.launching` and `jdt.launching.<your-operating-system>`. These runtime dependencies seem to be automatically resolved in some contexts, e.g. when running as a headless junit plugin test, but we had to manually specify them as requirements when running the same headless tests via Tycho.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.ant4eclipse.org/ for a project which allows you to work inside Eclipse projects.

I used it for a bit some years back, and found that this is too brittle for long term usage and build scripts.  I would recommend against relying on internal Eclipse things.  They break!  Typically when mixing releases.

Instead I would suggest you move to Maven.  This is a bit more work, but allows you to use the whole maven infrastructure and API's to do things.  What you want to achieve here, may be possible already using a Maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks. But ant4eclipse doesn't seem to export an API that can be directly used in a Java project.
Switching to Maven or Gradle could be a viable option, if there are already libraries to read the corresponding configurations and tools to turn Eclipse projects into Maven or Gradle projects.