# How get location of the source folder in Eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to get the source folder location of the project when user click on menu in the text editor (as I need to extract package path and the file name of the selected file).

If the project name is `UserProject` and source folder is src how can I get source location relative to the project as `UserProject\src`.

I have tried this to do this:

```
 IPath fullPath = file.getFullPath();
 String filePath = fullPath.toString();
```

But it contains full path of the source file as `UserProject\src\se\util\MyClass.java`

Comment: Can you split the `filePath` using "src" as the delimiter and then use the result to generate your source location path?

Comment: @IshitaSinha src is not same for all the projects since I am target to behave this as plugin for any project . It can be either name user preferred (src, sourceCode etc.)

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776230/is-it-possible-to-load-an-eclipse-java-project-using-jdt-in-the-headless-mode/37777685#37777685 . Use the JDT Core APIs.

Comment: Looks like you may be able to use `JavaCore.create(file)` to get the `IJavaElement` which presumably has this information.

Comment: @greg-449 In the "Plug-in Dependencies" library of the Eclipse project does not contains core.jar file which contains JavaCore class. Even I import it separately it fails at run time (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore). Does core.jar should included in the "Plug-in Dependencies" library automatically.

Comment: JavCore is in the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` plug-in which you must add to your plug-in's dependencies.

Comment: @greg-449 "Plug-in Dependencies" has predefined set of jars and it is read only. Can not add more jars to it. Any idea how to edit it?

Comment: Open the MANIFEST.MF editor, go to the Dependencies tab and click Add in the 'Required Plug-ins' section.

Comment: @greg-449 I have tried with IJavaElement and there was no way to get that information. So what I did is read the source file and extract the package path from there since it is a .java file.

Comment: You need to look at exactly what type the `IJavaElement` is, I think it will usually be `ICompilationUnit` in which case you can use the `getPackageDeclarations` method.

Comment: @greg-449 Your comments solve the issue. Please add it as answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Eclipse JDT `JavaCore.create(file)` call to get the an `IJavaElement` for the file.

`IJavaElement` is just the base interface for many of the JDT classes. You need to look at exactly what type the `IJavaElement` is, I think it will usually be `ICompilationUnit` in which case you can use the `getPackageDeclarations` method.

Answer (score 0):

This returns the project folder.

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

If you want the source folder, you can just do like this:

```
String str = System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "src";
```

Comment: System.getProperty("user.dir"); gives the eclipse workspace location instead of project.

Comment: This is not useful in Eclipse plug-ins